# Mock data from method while using GraphQlTester in test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, graphql, mockito

I am using Java Spring Boot 3.2.0 and am using GraphQL. For several of my GraphQL APIs, I need to reach out to different clients to obtain data. I have a GraphQL controller, a service class, and a client class for that flow.

The controller is the point of entry for my GraphQL query, and the service class is going to handle the specific logic needed for the query. The service class will call the client class which will handle the work to reach out to a specific client for the data. Everything I have right now is bare-bones, but the flow will remain the same.

I am not concerned with testing the client class, but I want to test my controller and service classes. However, I am not sure how to mock data returned from the client class while using GraphQlTester.

Here are the classes:

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerService service;

    public CustomerController(CustomerService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public List<Customer> queryCustomer(@Argument Long customerId) {
        return service.queryCustomer(customerId);
    }

}
```

Service class

```
@Component
public class CustomerService {

    private final MyClient myClient;

    public CustomerService(MyClient myClient) {
        this.myClient = myClient;
    }

    /***
     * Contains logic to query the appropriate client(s) for the Customer data.
     *
     * @param customerId the unique ID of the Customer
     *
     * @return List of Customers for the input customerId
     */
    public List<Customer> queryCustomer(Long customerId) {
        return myClient.getCustomerData(customerId);
    }

}
```

And the client class

```
@Component
public class MyClient {

    public List<Customer> getCustomerData(Long customerId) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This API is not yet implemented.");
    }

}
```

I am using GraphQlTester to help with the testing, but I want to be able to return mock data from MyClient, rather than having the client actually reach out to get data (also, the class is not fully implemented, so right now just throwing an exception...which I don't want to happen for my tests)

Here is the test class:

```
@Import({CustomerService.class, MyClient.class})
@GraphQlTest(CustomerController.class)
class CustomerControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    GraphQlTester graphQlTester;

    @Test
    void testQueryCustomer() {
        List<Customer> mockList = new ArrayList<>();
        mockList.add(new Customer(1234L, "test@test.com", "FirstName", "LastName"));

        MyClient myClient = mock(MyClient.class);
        when(myClient.getCustomerData(1234L)).thenReturn(mockList);

        graphQlTester.documentName("queryCustomerTest")
                .execute()
                .path("queryCustomer")
                .entityList(Customer.class)
                .satisfies(customers -> {
                    assertEquals(customers.size(), 1);
                });
    }

}
```

My GraphQL document

```
query queryCustomer($customerId: ID) {
    queryCustomer(customerId: $customerId)
    {
        customerId
        customerEmail
        firstName
        lastName
    }
}
```

And the Customer record

```
public record Customer(
        Long customerId,
        String customerEmail,
        String fistName,
        String lastName
) {
}
```

Now, I realize that my mock currently does not work this way, as I am still getting the exception returned when I execute the test:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response has 1 unexpected error(s) of 1 total. If expected, please filter them out: [[NotImplementedException]: This API is not yet implemented.]
```

I know I can filter out expected errors, but I would rather mock data being returned. How can I inject my mock data to return when MyClient.getCustomerData() is called? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Instead of using:

```
    MyClient myClient = mock(MyClient.class);
```

I had to add MockBean like this:

```
    @MockBean
    MyClient myClient;
```